# How to disable OverlayScrollbars when window width equal 600px?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I use [overlayScrollbars](https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars) to create a `<nav></nav>` .

When window width less than 600px, then navbar go left like sidebar.

```
    <ul>
      <li>test 1</li>
      <li>test 2</li>
      <li>test 3</li>
    </ul>
```

and create a js file and add this line:

```
$('ul').overlayScrollbars({ });
```

now when my widnow width less than 600px, overlayScrollbars worke fine but when my window width bigger than 600px, overlayScrollbars still work and  element width is like sidebar.

How can I disable overlayScrollbars() when my window width bigger than 600px?

Comment: maybe instance.sleep(); if it is bigger than 600px and instance.update() if it is less than 600px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Store the overlay instances as variables, so you can `.destroy()` them.
2. Check the window size when the page is opened, and create it depending on size.
3. Attach `.destroy()` and recreation of new instances to an `onresize` event, with the same check as when the page loads.

Here's an example of how to store and destroy with jQuery.

```
//initializes plugin and stores the instance into a variable
var instance = $('ul').overlayScrollbars({ }).overlayScrollbars();
instance.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ul id="test">
    <li>test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery

```
So you get it onload
--------------------

if($(window).width() < 600) {
    var instance = OverlayScrollbars(document.getElementById("test"), {});
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  var instance = OverlayScrollbars(document.getElementById("test"), {});
  if ($(window).width() > 600) {
    instance.destroy();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$(window).height(); $(window).width();` to check the width and height of page and then enable or disable stuffs with a basic `if else` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Query to hide elements from any screen!

Try it:

```
    <style>
      @media (min-width:600px){
        .yourOverlayElement{ display:none; }
      }
    </style>
```